# Inverse of Short-time Fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis

The Gabor transform (i.e. Short-time Fourier transform with some Gaussian window) can be defined by  (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_transform) :

$G_x(t_0,\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi(t-t_0)^2}e^{-2i\pi \xi t}x(t)\,dt$

On this page it is mentioned that *the Gabor transform is invertible*, and that *the original signal can be recovered by the following equation* :

$ x(t_0) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty G_x(t_0,\xi) e^{2i\pi t_0 \xi}\,d\xi$

Can somebody help me for a proof of that ?

I thought we would need $G_x(u,\xi)$ for all $\xi$ **and $u$ in a wide range** in order to reconstruct $x(t_0)$,  but here it seems that only $G_x(t_0,\xi)$ for all $\xi$ is needed. Is this true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok according to a book:

the Windowed Fourier transform is obtained by the formula:

$$Sf(u,\epsilon)=\int_\mathbb{R}f(t)g(t-u)e^{-i\epsilon t}dt$$

where $f$ and $g$ are the signal and window respectively:

and the reconstruction formula is given by:

$$f(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R}Sf(u,\epsilon)g(t-u)e^{i\epsilon t}d\epsilon du$$.

So I reckon you will need both $u$ and $\epsilon$, to reconstruct $f$.

Comment: yes! I also thought 2 integrations will be required in order to recover $f(t)$, so I don't understand how it could be possible with only $1$. Is there a mistake in Wikipedia here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_transform#Inverse_Gabor_transform ?

Comment: just for information, which book is it ?

Comment: @Basj: I think there is a mistake there.

Comment: @Basj: A wavelet tour of signal processing

Comment: Thanks. I don't know so much about Wikipedia editing. Can we put a "May contain a mistake, needs to be verified" sign there ?

Comment: Or maybe is there some magical thing that makes that **only one** integral is needed at the end when the window $g$ is a Gaussian window (Gabor transform) ?

Comment: No it should be true for all types of windows

Comment: Ok so it's a true mistake on wikipedia ?

Comment: @Basj, you can try editing on Wikipedia haha